# How to call Mobile App Event from the App?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-android

We have a Android App (Kotlin) and we declared Mobile App Events in Journey Builder.

We created a Journey with an entry source configured to respond to one of our Events and are struggling to trigger it from our App.

The documentation indicates the following [call example](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/event-tracking/event-tracking-event-tracking.html) :

```kotlin
val event = EventManager.customEvent("EventName", mapOf("key1" to "value2", "key2" to "value2"))
SFMCSdk.track(event)
```

However, when doing this, we get the following error :

```
Type mismatch.
Required: com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.components.events.Event?
Found: com.salesforce.marketingcloud.events.Event?
```

So we are stuck doing the call.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, we had the same error.
It happens that EventManager is of the wrong type.

This will work :

```kotlin
val event = com.salesforce.marketingcloud.sfmcsdk.components.events.EventManager.customEvent("Your Event")
SFMCSdk.track(event)
```

Comment: Thanks, we missed that one ;)

Answer (score 1):

This works here :

```kotlin
val event = EventManager.customEvent("Event")
event!!.track()
```

Comment: Compiles indeed, but accepting the above answer since EventManager seems of the right type.

Comment: That make sense. However, this code actually fires an App Event so both should work.

Comment: This should be `event?.track()` for safety. The creators, like `customEvent(string: String)` are intended to do validation and may not return a `null`.